# GCP project owner can't list builds or triggers

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I have the `owner` role on a GCP project. I created 2 build triggers, which are visible to me in the console.

[image: GCP console showing 2 build triggers]

I want to list these triggers using a service account and the [node.js client](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-cloudbuild).

I made a custom role and assigned `cloudbuild.builds.viewer` and I think the following should work, but it does not:

```
$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy myprojectid --flatten="bindings[].members" --format='table(bindings.role)' --filter="bindings.members:build-trigger-viewer@myprojectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
ROLE
roles/cloudbuild.builds.viewer
$ gcloud iam service-accounts keys create trigger-viewer-credentials.json --iam-account=build-trigger-viewer@myprojectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com
$ GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=trigger-viewer-credentials.json node
> var {CloudBuildClient} = require("@google-cloud/cloudbuild")
> var cb = new CloudBuildClient()
> await cb.listBuildTriggers({projectId: "myprojectid"})
[ [], null, null ]
```

Backing up from that, I've realised that for some reason listing these triggers or even builds from `gcloud` also fails.

```bash
$ gcloud beta builds triggers list
Listed 0 items.
$ gcloud builds list
Listed 0 items.
```

Just to verify I'm not insane:

```bash
$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy myprojectid | rg -A 1 user:myuser@mydomain.com
  - user:myuser@mydomain.com
  role: roles/container.admin
--
  - user:myuser@mydomain.com
  role: roles/gkehub.admin
--
  - user:myuser@mydomain.com
  role: roles/owner
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on what might be happening?

Comment: That you can't `gcloud build triggers list` (I assume using the same user account as in the Console?) suggests that you're using different projects. Please try explicitly referencing the Project `gcloud build trigger list --project=${PROJECT}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by the documentation, the command [`gcloud beta builds triggers list`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/builds/triggers/list) will list all the triggers in the global scope.

In your image you show that the triggers are in `northamerica-northeast1` so you may need to use the `—-region` flag.

In the case of the code you may need to set the `parent` as especified in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/cloudbuild/latest/cloudbuild/protos.google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1.listbuildtriggersrequest) which is the region where the trigger lives ([API reference](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers/list#query-parameters)), otherwise you're getting global triggers.

```
await cb.listBuildTriggers({
projectId: "myprojectid", 
parent: "projects/myprojectid/locations/northamerica-northeast1"
})
```

If the account didn't have permissions, you would get a 403 error and not empty results.

This also applies for `gcloud builds list`.